# Open HTML file on Android

Tags: android, html, tasker

There are some topics about this question but they are old and I can't believe there isn't a solution for this.

I have made an HTML file and placed it in the Download directory from Android.

When I try to open the file in Chrome, Firefox or Opera I get an error: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/mysite.html

We are living in 2021 and I can't believe this isn't possible.

Maybe Tasker can help?

Comment: What's the error? You only posted the path...

Answer (score 5):

**3 Options that can work, depending of the content of your file:**

1. You can use a local web server in your Android phone itself. There are many server apps out there in the Play Store, one such app is [Simple HTTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server).
2. You can put your documents into the folder `Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/` in the internal storage. It's absolute path is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/` or `/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/`. This is the location where Chrome stores any downloaded files and therefore, this is the only location where Chrome can access the files. But remember, uninstalling Chrome will delete this directory.
3. Also you can download a [HTML Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.html.htmlviewer) to open your file.