# How can I make html src attribute work normally in Android 11

Tags: html, src

When I make something that uses the `src` attribute in html, it works well in any browser on my pc, but when I started to test it on Android, iframes images and external script doesn't worked, it sayed that it not found for example
`<img src="img.png" alt="Image">`
This doesn't works on Android

I can make images work with `content://` on Android, but that is very long and hard to do, and external scripts and iframes don't work with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open HTML file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215016/open-html-file-on-android)

Comment: @A.Meshu No, I know how to open html file on android, but when I open it, external scripts images and iframes don't work, but on pc it works